# Is it possible to call Google Maps Javascript API from JS function and display it on ion-content?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have created my an Google Maps API snippet of code that displays a map in a box:

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var mapCenter = {
    lat: 50,
    lng: 50
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: mapCenter,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  map.setOptions({
    minZoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 20
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
</style>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>

  <div class="box" id="map">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Now, I would like to add this map in an *ion-content* that is included in the following:

```
    LoginModal = __decorate([
            Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["Component"])({
                selector: 'page-login-modal',template:
    '<ion-header class="{{customClasses}}">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>{{ title | translate }}
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="{{customClasses}}">
        <div class="box" id="map">
        </div>
    </ion-content>'
 }),], LoginModal);
    return LoginModal;
}());
```

For this reason I have created a JS function (in the same file as the ion-content) in order to make the Google Maps API call and pass my arguments:

```
    var map;
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap";
    LoginModal.prototype.initMap = function () {
         var mapCenter = {
            lat: 50,
            lng: 50
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 15,
             center: mapCenter,
            disableDefaultUI: true
         });
         map.setOptions({
            minZoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 20
         });
      };
```

The above code does not display the map but instead only the box. I have tried to place the *"src="https:"* line in the index.html file (in the body and in the head), but again only the box is displayed.

In order to test that my JS functions can alter the ion-context, I have created another function (next to initMap()) that was able to replace a photo with text upon pressing a button.

What change should I do in order to make it display the map (since I can make it happen in the JS snippet example above)?

Comment: Can you check the initMap() is directly available in you global scope. Google map calls the callback after loading it in the dom. I also do check whether the google service loaded or not

Comment: @Rohit.007 In order to test that my JS functions can alter the ion-context, I have created another function (next to initMap()) that was able to replace a photo with text upon pressing a button.

Comment: Can you share your code over stackbliz?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, try replicating it in your code and at last you need to call createMap().

Here is one app available, you can take a reference from it but it is for Bing

https://github.com/microsoft/Bing-Maps-Fleet-Tracker/tree/master/MobileClient

```js
private loadPromise: Promise<void>;

private load(): Promise < void > {
  if (this.loadPromise) {
    return this.loadPromise;
  }

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;

  const mapsCallback = 'initMap';
  script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<GOOGLE-MAP-KEY>&callback=initMap`;
  this.loadPromise = new Promise <
  void >
  ((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
    window[mapsCallback] = () => {
      this.loadLableMarker().then(() => {
        resolve();
      });
    };
    script.onerror = (error: Event) => {
      console.error('maps script error' + error);
      reject(error);
    };
  });

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return this.loadPromise;
}

createMap(element: HTMLElement, options): Promise {
  return this.load().then(() => {
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 15,
             center: mapCenter,
            disableDefaultUI: true
         });
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the JS code using TypeScripts for Ionic cordova